# PIC18f452 port listening issue

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, mikroc

Why doesn't this code work? All that I want is portb to toggle when I press a button.

```
main
trisb=0
trisa=0xff
while true
if ra0<>0 then
portb = not portb
end if
wend .end
```

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? Does the compiler provide an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what that is; is it pseudocode?

Anyway, you need to trigger on the CHANGE from RA0 == 0 to RA0 == 1.  As written, as long as RA0 == 1 then your PORTB will toggle every time through the loop.

Here's an example in C:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char bButtonValue = 0;

    TRISA = 0xFF;
    TRISB = 0x00;

    while (1)
    {
        if (RA0 != bButtonValue) 
        {
            bButtonValue = RA0;
            if (bButtonValue == 1)
            {
                 PORTB= ~PORTB;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Keep in mind that for a real app, you would want to debounce the switch input (make sure it's stable for a few samples before triggering the change event.

Comment: thnx adam
yep!! the mistake I failed in was 
rb0_bit,, also I must enable the interrupts con.
.. 
can I run two while true loops in pic, as threaded classes in java or c++??

Comment: First, please explain how you need interrupts for your original example.  Did you want to put the button scan in an interrupt?  If so, use a timer interrupt with a 10ms tick.  You can handle debouncing from there.

Comment: Also, you can run a loop in your interrupt service routine to scan the button and set a variable for your main loop to read.  This is the equivalent of multithreading in an embedded system with no RTOS.

Comment: that's it thank you mr Adam, i used interrupts to break the while true, another question:
is there any module supports IEEE 802.11 can be connected to pic18??
i wanna transmit data from a smartphone to pic18 via mobile wifi standards
thanks alot